# QuickBooks adding sales tax adjustments using QBFC

Tags: quickbooks, qbfc

I am trying to add a sales tax adjustment to QuickBooks using QBFC but I cannot figure out how to accomplish this. Any ideas would be appreciated. In order to do this in QuickBooks you need to right click on a tax code and then select  "Adjust Sales Tax Due"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sales tax adjustments are journal entries, so you would use the `JournalEntryAdd` message to create one. In order to understand how to set up a tax adjustment: first, create a tax adjustment, then take a look at the journal entry you created by going to Company -> Make General Journal Entry, then set the List of Selected Journal Entries selector to "This Month". You should see the tax adjustment in the list. You can highlight it to see the debit and credit that was created by the adjustment, as well as the tax vendor assignment.